# Motivation for Banach Space in Global Picard-Lindelöf

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems

I'm looking for the motivation of the core idea to a proof of the global existence version of Picard-Lindelöf.

> **Global Picard-Lindelöf.** Let $f:[a,b] \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be continuous and
>   (globally) Lipschitz in $y$. Then there is a global solution $y:[a,b]
>  \to \mathbb{R}^n$ for each $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ to the ODE $$ y' =
>  f(x,y), \ y(a) = y_0.$$

The main idea of one proof is to use Banach's Fixed Point Theorem on a special Banach Space, namely some sort of $\mathcal{C}([a,b], \mathbb{R}^n)$ with a *weighted supremum-norm*
$$ ||y|| := \sup_{x \in [a,b]} e^{-\beta x} |y(x)|$$
with Lipschitz constant $L$ and $\beta > L$.

So my question: Where did that norm come from? What's the motivation to that? Is it just some space that I will become more familiar with in my further studies? And even so - where did it come from then?

Comment: I did not verify it but my guess is that this weighted norm is defined to avoid some issues that appear when we try to use the Bannach Fixed Point Theorem to prove Picard's theorem. The problem is that the map $F(\gamma) = \int f(t,\gamma(t))dt$ -- which leads to the solution to the ODE -- is not a contraction for the suppremum norm.  In order to use the Bannach Fixed Point Theorem, one has to adapt the norm or prove that some power $F^n$ is a contraction.

Comment: Yes, indeed, the supremum norm doesn't give us a contraction and I just tried a different weight ($\frac{1}{bx}$ instead of $e^{-bx}) but that doesn't seem to work either. So I'm wondering what the motivation for the chosen weight is. Perhaps it's just a weight that falls quickly enough? But why'd we want that? (oh and I fixed a little typo in the weight of my post)

Comment: I think there is no special reason to choose this weight besides that it gives us a Banach space and makes $F$ a contraction. For example, once we know that $F^n$ is a contraction for the sup norm, we can define a metric $d(\gamma,\delta) =  \|\gamma-\delta \| + l^{-1} \| F(\gamma) -F(\delta) \| + \dots + l^{1-n} \| F^{n-1}(\gamma) - F^{n-1}(\delta)\|$ where $l^n$ is the Lipschitz constant of $F^n$. This gives a complete metric space and makes $F$ a contraction.

Comment: Ah, that approach is interesting! Is it easy to prove that $F^n$ is a contraction for the sup norm? And hm, yes, it does seem like quite an arbitrary weight to choose but it's not completely random, right? I mean like why should intuitively that weight work and others not.

Comment: To prove that $F^n$ is a contraction for some $n$ we use the Lipschitz condition to show that $\| F^n(\gamma) - F^n(\delta)\| < C_n \|\gamma -\delta\|$ and $C_n <1$ is $n$ is large enough.

Comment: @Kezer To reply to your latest comment: The [Grönwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality) gives that $\lVert y(x)\rVert\le\lVert y(a)\rVert e^{L(x-a)}$ for $x\in[a,b]$, so multiplying by $\exp({\color{red}\beta(x-a)})$ (sort of) balances the growth. Incidentally, you have colliding notations: $b$ stands for both the right end of the interval and the coefficient.

Comment: @user539887 Ah, that's great. I was looking for something like this. Thank you very much! And I fixed the colliding notation issue.

Comment: @Kezer I see that I made a misprint: multiplying by $\exp({\color{red}-}\beta(x-a))$ ...