# Question about the uniqueness and existence of solution to a second order linear differntial equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

When I search for the theorem on the uniqueness and existence of solution to a second order linear differential equation I get:

Given the second
order linear equation
$$
y′′+ p(x) y′+ q(x) y = f(x). 
$$
Let $a$ be any point on the interval $I$, and let $\alpha$ and $\beta$
be any two real numbers. Then the initial-value problem
$$
y′′+ p(x) y′+ q(x) y = f(x), y (a) = \alpha, y′(a) = \beta
$$
has a unique solution.

Here does the interval $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ only meant to be a finite interval?
or does it hold for $I = \mathbb{R}$ as well? Assuming $p,q,f$ are continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. I wanted to clarify as I could not find a reference where this is made clear... thank you

Comment: $I$ is  priori a "small" neighborhood of $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the first order system
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\pmatrix{y(x)\\y'(x)}
=\pmatrix{0&1\\-q(x)&-p(x)}\pmatrix{y(x)\\y'(x)}
$$
Then over any bounded interval $J\subset I$ the maximum of the matrix norm is a Lipschitz constant for the first-order system on the slice $J\times\Bbb R^2$. So you get the existence of a unique solution on $J$. Now consider a nested sequence of bounded intervals that cover or converge to $I$. It follows that there exists a unique global solution.

See also

- [Existence of solution for second-order linear differential equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3386203/existence-of-solution-for-second-order-linear-differential-equations)
- [Globally Lipschitz implies solutions exist for all time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236413/globally-lipschitz-implies-solutions-exist-for-all-time)